# Downloading file in capybara without rails

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, capybara

Scenario: Trying to visit external url via capybara to download a file. Selenium or webkit must be used as a driver. Rack-test cant be used because it doesnt allow visiting external urls.

The site uses iframes.

The file download is prompted via javascript like this:

```
    <a href="javascript:OpenFile('****.pdf', 2)">some_text_here</a>
```

clicking the link prompts a native browser download confirm box.
I have tried the following methods:
**Selenium driver:**

- using custom profile -> no effect, the popup still appears

  ```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new 
  profile['browser.download.dir'] = "~/Downloads"
  profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf"
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => >profile)
  end
  ```
- using javascript before clicking link-> no effect

  ```
  within_frame(1) do
    page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
    find(:xpath,"//span[@class='BoldText']/a").click
  end
  ```
- trying to use alert -> not found even though the download box appears

  ```
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
  -> No alert is present
  ```

**Webkit driver:**

- trying to use javascript -> file is not being downloaded
- page.accept_confirm not finding any links

How to download the file?

Comment: do you have `describe "title", :js => true do`?

Comment: Your custom profile method should work (it's a bit weird naming the driver :webkit when it's using firefox though) as long as the document is being identified as 'application/pdf' and not something else like 'application/octet-stream' - you can try  `profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf, application/octet-stream"` or verify in your app that it is actually reporting the file with the application/pdf type.  Other profile settings that may be necessary are `profile['pdfs.disabled'] = true` and `profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2`  so it uses your directory

Comment: Thanks alot Tom Walpole, the application was indeed reporting the file with the application/octet-stream type. Naming the driver :webkit was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The application was reporting the file with application/octet-stream type. Adding

```
    profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf, application/octet-stream"
```

solved the problem in this case.